creating a data dictionary via snowflake query?
I figured I could easily create a basic data dictionary of the schema my team is working out of. I currently have this:
WITH column_metadata AS (
    SELECT 
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME,
        DATA_TYPE,
        IS_NULLABLE
    FROM 
        DEV_RAW.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'WORKDAY_SANDBOX'
    ORDER BY 
        TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
),
example_values AS (
    SELECT
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR', 'TEXT', 'CHAR') THEN MAX(CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS STRING))
            WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT', 'DOUBLE', 'INT', 'BIGINT') THEN MAX(COLUMN_NAME::VARCHAR)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Example_Value
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                TABLE_SCHEMA,
                TABLE_NAME,
                COLUMN_NAME,
                DATA_TYPE,
                CASE 
                    WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR', 'TEXT', 'CHAR') THEN COLUMN_NAME::VARCHAR
                    WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT', 'DOUBLE', 'INT', 'BIGINT') THEN COLUMN_NAME::VARCHAR
                    ELSE NULL
                END AS COLUMN_VALUE
            FROM 
                DEV_RAW.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE 
                TABLE_SCHEMA = 'WORKDAY_SANDBOX'
        )
    GROUP BY 
        TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
)
SELECT 
    cm.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    cm.TABLE_NAME,
    cm.COLUMN_NAME,
    cm.DATA_TYPE,
    cm.IS_NULLABLE,
    ev.Example_Value
FROM 
    column_metadata cm
LEFT JOIN 
    example_values ev
ON 
    cm.TABLE_SCHEMA = ev.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND cm.TABLE_NAME = ev.TABLE_NAME
    AND cm.COLUMN_NAME = ev.COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY 
    cm.TABLE_SCHEMA, cm.TABLE_NAME, cm.COLUMN_NAME;

and it's doing everything I need it to besides the ev.Example_Value part is just returning the column headers instead of an actual piece of data below the headers in the tables. Any ideas?

To get actual data values you need to query the table that contains the data, you can’t get this data from the information schema

@NickW ah so I'd have to specify the actual table name and just manually query every table and like select * from table_name limit 1;

Yes, though obviously you can dynamically create each select statement and execute it in code - if you wanted to
